# how to run Two Proportion Z-Test if I run the test over entire population

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval, t-test, abtest, z-test

I know Z test is applied for Test concerning two proportions.

Let there be two treatments with population proportions
p1 and p2 and sample sizes of n1 and n2 respectively.
Samples associated with a certain event are x1 and x2 with
the respective proportions.

But I applied over the whole population i.e. n1=n2=n.

Will this test be valid then?[image]

Answer (score 0):

No. There are validity conditions to conduct a test of two proportions.

- The sampling method for each population is simple random sampling.
- The samples are independent.
- Each sample includes at least 10 successes and 10 failures.
- Each population is at least 20 times as big as its sample.

The first and fourth bullet points fail.